# jQuery Returns only native dom objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http, web

I have a huge problem. I want to select a DOM-Element using jQuery. This happens inside an AngularJS http-request. It works when runtime has past but when I call the function immediately after the page load, jQuery returns only a native JS DOM-Object.

The code is nothing special. It's only:

```
$http({ "methode" : "GET", "url" : <URL>, "cache" : true })
.success(function(data){
   ...
   var jQueryElement = jQuery("#" + params.elemId);
   jQueryElement[0].previousElementSibling.children[1].classList.add("active");
   ...
});
```

This request is inside a function of an angularjs controller.
How I said before, when it's called directly after the page load jQuery( ... ) only returns a native DOM-object.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: with jqueryobject[number] you get native dom elements

Comment: If you need to set only class on an element, I would rather recommend setting scope variable, and use ng-class directive on element

Comment: I also use jQuery.parent() and some other jQuery functions.

@RolandStarke : yes I know but what jQuery returns lools like this: Object { "content" : { ... }, "selector" : { .. }

So there is no jQueryObject[<number>]

Comment: whats the error message you are getting?

Comment: It's the usal: jqueryElement[0] is undefined

Comment: I can't understand this. It only happends on page load. When the function is called while runntime, there are no problems at all.

Comment: thats because there is no element with the id `params.elemId` the time you first call your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved to problem by emitting an event when the content is fully loadet. 
The function with the function now listens to this event an starts the http-request after the event.

Thanks to Roland Starke. It was such an obvious reason why it doesn't work.